# Multilevel sorting for array of objects - javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to do multilevel ascending order sorting for below array of objects.

```js
var array = [{id: 1, color: 'red', objname: 'tomato'},
{id: 1, color: 'orange', objname: 'pumpkin'},
{id: 2, color: 'red', objname: 'tomato' },
{id: 1, color: 'red', objname: 'cherry' },
{id: 1, color: 'orange', objname: 'sunset'}];


Expected result Array:

var resultArray = 
[{id: 1, color: 'orange', objname: 'pumpkin'},
{id: 1, color: 'orange', objname: 'sunset'},
{id: 1, color: 'red', objname: 'cherry'},
{id: 1, color: 'red', objname: 'tomato'},
{id: 2, color: 'red', objname: 'tomato'}];
```

From above array of objects, first i want to sort 'id' level and color and finally objname. First level based on id I can able to do but with in that multilevel i dont have idea to sort.
And this is how I'm sorting one level,

```js
sortById(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
```

With this i can ascending array of objects based on 'id'.
Can any one help me, how can we perform multilevel sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can `sort` it with multiple `OR` conditions:

```js
var array = [{id: 1, color: 'red', objname: 'tomato'},{id: 1, color: 'orange', objname: 'pumpkin'},{id: 2, color: 'red', objname: 'tomato' },{id: 1, color: 'red', objname: 'cherry' },{id: 1, color: 'orange', objname: 'sunset'}];

var resultArray = array.sort((a,b)=>{
   return a.id-b.id || a.color.localeCompare(b.color) || a.objname.localeCompare(b.objname)
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a dynamic approach by collecting the wanted keys and use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a short circuit for [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, color: 'red', objname: 'tomato' }, { id: 1, color: 'orange', objname: 'pumpkin' }, { id: 2, color: 'red', objname: 'tomato' }, { id: 1, color: 'red', objname: 'cherry' }, { id: 1, color: 'orange', objname: 'sunset' }],
    keys = ['id', 'color', 'objname'];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    var result;
    keys.some(k => result = (a[k] > b[k]) - (a[k] < b[k]));
    return result;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
var array = [{id: 1, color: 'red', objname: 'tomato'},
{id: 1, color: 'orange', objname: 'pumpkin'},
{id: 2, color: 'red', objname: 'tomato' },
{id: 1, color: 'red', objname: 'cherry' },
{id: 1, color: 'orange', objname: 'sunset'}];

array.sort((a, b) => {          
      if (a.city === b.city) {
        if(a.color === b.color) {
          return (a.objname).localeCompare(b.objname)
        }
        return (a.color).localeCompare(b.color)
      }
      return a.id - b.id
  }
);

console.log(array);
```